# Getting 413 from Jetty 6 cookie size limit

Tags: java, cookies, jetty, equinox

I'm getting HTTP error 413 from Jetty 6 for cookie size limit. I tried to search for this, but the only thing I found is that such configuration is applicable for Jetty 7 - 9

In case of Jetty 7 it is:

```
<Set name="headerBufferSize">16192</Set>
```

for Jetty 9 it is:

```
<Set name="requestHeaderSize">16192</Set>
```

Adding it to the *connectors* configuration.

I couldn't find such property for Jetty 6 and I'm wondering does it even exists or it is only for newer versions of Jetty.